# can anyone help me to make PCA 3D box plots?

Tags: r, pca3d

I used the below code to do 3D PCA, all I want to make a 3D box plot.

```
Mydata = read.csv("PCA.csv")
head(Mydata)
pca = prcomp(Mydata[,6:11], scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca)
library(pca3d)
gr = factor(Mydata[,1])
pca3d(pca, group = gr)
dput(Mydata)
pca3d(pca,title = "Nanjing", axes.color= "black",group=gr, show.ellipses=TRUE,
      ellipse.ci=0.95,biplot=TRUE, biplot.vars=3, show.centroids= TRUE,show.group.labels=FALSE, show.plane=FALSE, legend = "topleft")
```

To download the image I used

```
snapshotPCA3d(file="Nanjing.png")
```

but it didn't work, it is showing a warning text which I didn't understand (look below)

Warning messages:
1: In rgl.snapshot(filename = file, fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
2: In rgl.snapshot(filename = file, fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
3: In rgl.snapshot(filename = file, fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Error: Invalid IHDR data
4: In rgl.snapshot(filename = file, fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Error: an error occured
5: In rgl.snapshot(filename = file, fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
'rgl.snapshot' failed

Data I used

```
structure(list(Location = c("Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", "Ningde Coastal Area", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay"), Serial = c(14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L), Station = c("NDDZ031", "NDDZ034", "NDDZ035", 
"NDDZ041", "NDDZ046", "NDDZ048", "NDDZ050", "NDDZ055", "NDDZ058", 
"NDDZ065", "NDDZ066", "NDDZ068", "NDDZ072", "NDDZ073", "NDDZ074", 
"NDDZ080", "NDDZ082", "NDDZ91", "NDDZ92", "NDDZ94", "NDDZ95", 
"NDDZ96", "NDDZ97", "NDDZ98", "NDDZ99", "NDDZ103", "NDDZ105", 
"NDDZ106", "NDDZ107", "NDDZ112", "NDDZ113", "NDDZ114", "NDDZ115", 
"NDDZ116", "NDDZ117", "NDDZ119", "NDDZ122", "NDDZ123"), Longitude = c(119.8156314, 
119.8109757, 119.9013884, 120.1667206, 120.0796901, 119.7829741, 
119.9602213, 119.7401038, 120.1113902, 119.7060803, 120.1239972, 
119.7798066, 120.0968136, 119.7086703, 119.7827459, 120.0751752, 
120.0621476, 119.6875, 119.6641667, 119.7163889, 119.7425, 119.69, 
119.7719444, 119.6622222, 119.7544444, 119.6644444, 119.6875, 
119.7369444, 119.7672222, 119.6583333, 119.6327778, 119.5991667, 
119.6769444, 119.7019444, 119.7419444, 119.6216667, 119.6722222, 
119.6408333), Latitude = c(26.48095232, 26.51638163, 26.53300528, 
26.54343039, 26.56656159, 26.59238665, 26.6023812, 26.62635719, 
26.64614884, 26.70021888, 26.70684282, 26.72669529, 26.75513142, 
26.77262578, 26.7665767, 26.82756691, 26.6238606, 26.34944444, 
26.35972222, 26.36, 26.36027778, 26.37583333, 26.38277778, 26.38638889, 
26.39277778, 26.41055556, 26.41972222, 26.42833333, 26.42861111, 
26.43361111, 26.44416667, 26.45, 26.45, 26.44805556, 26.44805556, 
26.46638889, 26.47166667, 26.4775), MPs = c(101.1310963, 126.7889088, 
85.74767297, 153.5234525, 51.35979247, 42.82041038, 214.4548942, 
96.9063435, 155.5864259, 46.01889546, 97.50099786, 78.36325034, 
161.375366, 99.76091135, 59.82528502, 98.7524581, 110.3141717, 
89.08, 103.02, 89.61, 106.42, 36.85, 66.93, 81.39, 152.58, 171.61, 
105.34, 148.31, 293.68, 279.4, 248.44, 273.39, 131.06, 36.33, 
29.62, 89.07, 382.31, 170.27), Petrolium = c(26.41089103, 5.575674479, 
112.1713291, 15.76231172, 28.05251105, 15.56603488, 34.78641497, 
20.95268019, 11.97087574, 28.16452888, 45.10068937, 32.00209717, 
1.098327442, 195.4523585, 94.0545153, 20.3648651, 19.08090108, 
20.26723856, 35.12860786, 38.00639611, 485.9158071, 6.801285888, 
130.2613429, 26.41691724, 21.47363409, 75.24255785, 9.088017875, 
17.83869051, 106.4365614, 367.7372615, 26.95847112, 42.01753212, 
17.56582294, 72.00256098, 382.5705508, 150.0004825, 452.8679126, 
61.51137016), Sulfide = c(5.19, 0, 72.82, 19.49, 2.93, 0, 43.95, 
1.37, 23.27, 12.19, 35.69, 77.05, 4.03, 65.29, 55.12, 29.95, 
14.93, 15.16, 47.67, 30.23, 75.05, 10.51, 38.75, 21.64, 35.97, 
122.53, 6.95, 58.52, 75.92, 92.23, 10.85, 72.1, 28.46, 81.19, 
195.59, 42.54, 277.4, 81.67), PCB = c(5.76, 1.44, 8.84, 11.92, 
3.4, 17.08, 0.56, 10.56, 5.24, 1.96, 6.44, 9.44, 10.28, 12.92, 
14.52, 0, 7.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PAH = c(23.36922085, 24.88374369, 21.49366333, 
25.69248678, 27.47334181, 36.56726931, 478.4803895, 39.12822287, 
17.2462056, 29.30102312, 232.0038657, 98.88904227, 22.6525315, 
31.41940388, 29.73926409, 36.20400715, 28.34097634, 0.0479, 0.0638, 
0.1312, 0.1293, 0.0589, 0.1032, 0.2725, 0.0712, 0.1173, 0.0703, 
0.2097, 0.1261, 0.0685, 0.0796, 0.1353, 0.0354, 0.0323, 0.034, 
0.0269, 0.0952, 0.0269), OCP = c(0.165265157, 0.004517346, 0.417073616, 
2.155375191, 0, 23.48084273, 0, 2.096700845, 1.852219063, 0.074522052, 
0.694281604, 0.112198511, 0.171174141, 4.644606351, 0.969985822, 
1.942156359, 2.36619641, 0.01071845, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004247812, 
0, 0, 0, 0.002020821, 0, 0.055799207, 0.003690873, 0.019063717, 
0, 0.173323781, 0.010429405, 0, 0, 0.013486877, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Without any of your data, we can't run your code, and we can't see any of the output you're trying to change

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works:

```
rgl.snapshot(filename = "PCA7gr.png",fmt="png",webshot2=TRUE)
```